# Track files without including them in the commits

Tags: git, version-control, commit, gitignore

So it happened a couple of times when I would be working on connected projects that this scenario took place:

1. I would make a minor change to one of the config files or comment out something in a file am not tracking to test stuff.
2. Forget to revert the changes.
3. Come back after a while to test things that work with the initial version of the file.
4. Waste lots of time debugging to find out step 2 was the problem.

Now I was wondering, is it possible to track some files but automatically ignore them when committing ? Think of it as a more lenient version of the `.gitignore` where I can choose some files to track while am developing locally, but they would never be committed.
I was thinking I could make a script that unstages those specific files in the then runs the commit. However, is there something I should be paying attention to ? Or perhaps there's already a way my quick search didn't pick up?

Comment: [This is a Git Frequently Asked Question.](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want here is to enable `--skip-worktree` bit for the configuration file.

First, ensure that git tracks the file existence by committing it at least once:

```
% git add Config.file
% git commit -m 'Configuration added'
```

Then flip the `--skip-worktree` bit:

```
% git update-index --skip-worktree Config.file
```

From this point forward all changes you make to the file will be ignored by git.

In order to see the changes and restore the file you can get use of the following git aliases:

```
[alias]
    diffsw = !git update-index --no-skip-worktree $1 && git diff -- $1 && git update-index --skip-worktree $1 && :
    restoresw = !git update-index --no-skip-worktree $1 && git restore -- $1 && git update-index --skip-worktree $1 && :
```

The first one shows the changes of the untracked file and can be used like this:

```
% git diffsw Config.file
```

The second one restores the file to the state it was last time commited:

```
% git restoresw Config.file
```

**P.S.** This, however, affects only local repo, you cannot push this bit.

Comment: From what I understood, I will not be able to see that the file has changed. Thing is I do want to detect that a file changed but still ignore it when I commit.

Comment: @minasrc git either tracks changes or ignores them. You can enable/disable the bit when needed but it tends to be quite verbose, so you may get help of aliases here. I added a couple for vital commands in my answer, but if you need anything more than that, you are free to write any shell script in place of the aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a *template* for a configuration file in source control. When it comes time to actually *configure* a service, edit a *copy* of the template to provide a valid configuration. The actual configuration file never gets tracked.

Comment: I am not versioning the actual config, it is ignored and I have a template. My problem is when I work locally and make changes, sometimes, I forget to revert them and I do not notice it, specifically because the file is not tracked. What I want is a way to detect the change without risking that the actual file is not ignored when I commit.

Comment: Make changes to what? It sounds like you are editing the template directly, rather than making a *copy* of the template. You should never have to "revert" anything you do to the configuration; it's a disposable artifact. If you need to change the configuration, start with the template again and make changes to a fresh copy. If that involves many of the same changes, make a more specific template to work with. In short, don't change files whose changes you don't want committed.

Comment: I have a config.example ( tracked ) and the actual config file (ignored) for my dev environment. Because the change was small ( changing a domain name) I was changing the config directly without making a copy. You are right though, my approach of wanting to have a on/off switch to track certain files in the `.gitignore` then untrack them defies the purpose of the file and could pose a risk.

Comment: More generally, never run the code in your Git working directory.  Your Git working directory is an input to a (possibly trivial) build tool, whose output is the input to a (possibly trivial) deployment tool. Once you have built and deployed your code, *then* you can execute it. (By trivial, I mean they may both simply copy files from one directory to another, but it prevents the temptation for editing anything in your Git working directory that isn't supposed to be edited.)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by *running code* in your git working directory?

Answer (score 1):

The painless, non-special, straight forward way to do this is to **track test stuff by creating separate commits for this, with a commit message having a format that stands out clearly**.

What I do is to check in such changes with commit messages on the format `"==== ...details... ===="`. No normal commits have these equal sign pre/post-fixes, so with this it is simple to remove them with interactive rebase before doing a final merge.

Example:

Say you add a `console.log` statement for debugging but this is not something you want to push in the end when you are finished, but for now you want to have it present. Solution: Add that console.log statement as its own commit and check in with commit message `"==== added debug in somefile.ts ====`.

Say you have some untracked files in the repository that are local to you only (draft emails, file copies, log files or whatever) and not something other team members should have their `.gitignore` polluted with. But those files represent noise for you when running `git status` and prevents using `git add .` etc. Solution: Add all your untracked files to `.gitignore` and check in with commit message `"==== my local .gitignore ===="`.

Say you want to temporarily limit unit tests to just the ones that are relevant to the part you are working on (e.g. [fdescribe](https://jasmine.github.io/api/4.3/global.html#fdescribe) using jasmine). Solution: Check in that as `"==== fdescribe some-thing.spec.ts ===="` (be a bit careful with excluding tests like this and ALWAYS run [git-test](https://github.com/mhagger/git-test) on all the commits on the branch without excluding any tests before the end).

In this example imagine that the branch ends up with the following commits in the end:

```
pick 100001 Created somefile.ts
pick 100002 Moved stuff from otherfile.ts to somefile.ts
pick 100003 ==== added debug in somefile.ts ====
pick 100004 Fix for some bug detected
pick 100005 ==== my local .gitignore ====
pick 100006 Add unit tests for something
pick 100007 ==== fdescribe some-thing.spec.ts ====
pick 100008 Delete no longer used function
```

Se how trivial it is to clean up every single bit of "test stuff" with zero mental effort required?
(remember running git-test on this branch)

```
pick 100001 Created somefile.ts
pick 100002 Moved stuff from otherfile.ts to somefile.ts
pick 100004 Fix for some bug detected
pick 100006 Add unit tests for something
pick 100008 Delete no longer used function
```

The benefits of committing all such *test stuff* as normal commits are that
they are **not hidden** and they receive all of git's normal benefits:

- They can be cherry-picked.
- They can be rebased.
- They can quickly be temporary disabled with `git revert`.
- They could eventually be shared with other people (they just need to be aware with your naming convention).
- Should they be accidentally be pushed to upstream branches they stick out as a sore thumb and can easily be identified and reverted.

And there is no git repo specific configuration!

---

> But I might get rebase conflicts when I remove those commits in an interactive rebase!

Use my script [git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3). [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) automatically resolves lines removed next to lines above/below that are changes (and if manual conflict resolution should be required KDiff3 is an awesome tool to use for that as well).

Comment: And notice that test stuff from one branch does not leak into other branches with this!

Comment: I was thinking partial commits would fit my case but I soon understood how cumbersome it can get when it's no longer concerning a whole file but specific lines. So thank you for sharing your approach, might be a bit mentally taxing for me to maintain this workflow at first but I think getting into the habit of more granular commits is a nice thing to have.