# Git rm --cached only for one branch

Tags: git, caching, merge, git-merge

On my development branch, I didn't want to track some json file.
So i `git rm --cached jsonFolder` and added it to gitIgnore.

I do need to keep it on my main branch.

Problem is, once on main branch, when i `git merge development`, it erase my `jsonFolder`.

I tried doing a `git restore --source main --worktree jsonFolder`
Then wanted to `git add jsonFolder` to track it.

Tells me `The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files`
which makes sense.

So I tried to `git checkout --ours .gitignore`
which tells me `Updated 0 paths from the index`, which is weird, I checked, and the gitignore on my main branch does not include `jsonFolder`.

I had to manually changed my `.gitignore` then `git add jsonFolder` for it to be tracked.

Seems very cumbersome.
What is a proper workflow to have a folder ignored in one branch, but not another ?
Also, why did `git checkout --ours .gitignore` didn't work?

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you're using Git, don't remove stuff just because you're not working on it. Git *needs* to put *every file* into every commit. Git does this using space-saving content-de-duplicating magic so that the unchanged files literally take *no space*. So just leave them there. If you need to modify them temporarily, and don't wish to "see" them as changed, consider using `--assume-unchanged` or `--skip-worktree` but be aware that these aren't the intended uses of the flags (see the [FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_do_I_tell_Git_to_ignore_tracked_files.3F)).

Comment: Note that files, in Git, are not in *branches*. (They're not even in folders—Git stores the files with names like `path/to/file` and creates the folders dynamically for your OS as needed.) The files wind up in *commits*, and each commit can be on zero or more branches; once you merge something, the commits that were only on one branch are now on two or more branches. So that leads to the "don't remove files" rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is, once on main branch, when i git merge development, it erase my `jsonFolder`.

You can then [`git restore -s @~ -- theFolder/`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) after the merge, in order to... restore the folder content.
And commit.

This assumes you just made the merge and `@` ([HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emem)) is the merge commit.
Fro [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADmaster3em), `@~` is the first parent, the "commit before the merge".

Since the deletion from `development` was already merged once, any subsequent merge from `development` to `main` will not delete that folder again.

Comment: Thanks ! 
I saw the `-s` is equivalent to `--source`, I couldn't find in the link you shared what the `@~` stands for?  or the `--` alone?
Could you please detail a bit what those shorthands do ?

Comment: @Sequoya `@~` is `HEAD~` (the commit before HEAD), assuming you just made the merge. Replace it be "the commit from `main` *before* the merge".

Answer (score 0):

> What is a proper workflow to have a folder ignored in one branch, but not another ?

As I [recently wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73179965/23118), the proper way to handle any such temporary "ignore on this branch only", "debug code", etc is to check it in as a separate commit, but with a commit message that stands out clearly as this kind of temporary.

So for your case, this would translate into

```bash
git checkout development
git rm --cached jsonFolder
echo jsonFolder/ >> .gitignore
git commit -m "==== ignore jsonFolder/ ===="
```

then before merging development into main you remove this (and other such "test stuff" commits") with an interactive rebase, e.g.

```bash
git checkout development
git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges $(git merge-base main development)
# Delete all your "==== ... ====" commits.
# Run git-test afterwords.
git checkout main
git merge development
```